# SQL columns to string

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query like this (pseudo code)

```
Select ID, TEXT, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 from blabla
```

but what I need is a query with 3 columns

```
Select ID, TEXT, STRING(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) from blabla
```

can I do this with just SQL?

EDIT:

Extra question:
It doesn't work if 1-7 return NULL or nothing. How can i convert NULL to an empty string? (MySQL 2005)

Comment: What database system and what version of it?? String handling is quite vendor- and product-specific...

Comment: MySQL 2005 ?? Do you mean MySQL (that is numbered versions 4, 5, 6) or do you mean Microsoft SQL Server (which has a version 2005) .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In T-SQL / MS-SQL:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862(SQL.80).aspx)

```
# With Space
SELECT ID, TEXT, 
  (1 + ' ' + 2 + ' ' + 3 + ' ' + 4 ' ' + 5 + ' ' + 6 + ' ' + 7) as Merged 
FROM blabla

# Without Space
SELECT ID, TEXT, 
  (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) as Merged 
FROM blabla
```

[In My-SQL:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
# With Space
SELECT ID, TEXT, 
  CONCAT_WS(' ', 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7) as Merged 
FROM blabla

# Without Space
SELECT ID, TEXT, 
  CONCAT(1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7) as Merged 
FROM blabla
```

[In PL-SQL/Oracle:](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php)

```
# With Space
SELECT ID, TEXT, 
  1 || ' ' || 2 || ' ' || 3 || ' ' || 4 || ' ' || 5 || ' ' || 6 || ' ' || 7 as Merged 
FROM blabla

# Without Space
SELECT ID, TEXT, 
  1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 as Merged 
FROM blabla
```

Comment: Although you have to do CAST(1 AS nvarchar) + ' ' + CAST(2 AS nvarchar) + ... in SQL Server whenever you are concatenating values not typed as string.

Answer (score 1):

In [t-sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

```
Select ID, TEXT, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 from blabla
```

In [PL-SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php):

```
Select ID, TEXT, 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 from blabla
```

In [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
Select ID, TEXT, CONCAT(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) from blabla
```

convert/casts may be required depending on the data types of columns 1 - 7

Comment: How do I convert/cast  NULL to '' in MS-SQL?

Comment: @nickik: use the `ISNULL(column, "")` construct

Answer (score 0):

Just us the + character to concatenate strings, assuming your 1-7 are string fields:

```
Select ID, TEXT, 1 + ' ' + 2 + ' ' + 3 + ' ' +
4 + ' ' + 5 + ' ' + 6 + ' ' + 7 as YourFieldName from blabla
```

I've included spaces between the fields, however you could also provide a comma or other delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

If my unterstanding is correct :

Select ID, TEXT, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7' from blabla;

Answer (score 0):

Select ID,TEXT,'1','2','3','4','5','6','7' from blabla;

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID, 
       TEXT, 
       CONCAT_WS(',', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) as Concatenated
  from blabla
```

or

```
Select ID, 
       TEXT, 
       CONCAT(1, ',', 2, ',', 3, ',', 4, ',', 5, ',', 6, ',', 7) as Concatenated
  from blabla
```

in MySQL

```
Select ID, 
       TEXT, 
       1 || ',' || 2 || ',' || 3 || ',' || 4 || ',' || 5 || ',' || 6 || ',' || 7) as Concatenated
  from blabla
```

in Oracle

but depends on your flavour of database

Answer (score 0):

i think its not possible to use a comma instead of plus